# changing the title of a button to new title when clicked and back to the original one after some seconds in swift

Tags: swift, uikit

Briefly, I am trying to change the title of a button to new title when clicked and back to the original title after some seconds.

So far, I could get the following result.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var currentButtonTitle: UIButton!
    
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        playSound(soundName: sender.currentTitle!)
        
        sender.alpha = 0.5
        sender.setTitle("yay", for: .normal)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            sender.alpha = 1.0
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.8) {
            sender.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        }
        
    }
    
    func playSound(soundName: String) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundName, withExtension: "wav")
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player.play()
                
    }
}
```

But I do not know how to get the original title back.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your keyPressed function, get the button’s current title before setting the new title. Then use that variable to reset the title in the asyncAfter block.

```
@IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    playSound(soundName: sender.currentTitle!)

    let oldTitle = sender.title(for: .normal)
    
    sender.alpha = 0.5
    sender.setTitle("yay", for: .normal)
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
        sender.alpha = 1.0
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.8) {
        sender.setTitle(oldTitle, for: .normal)
    }
    
}
```